# Twitter bootstrap: 1 sidebar 1 fluid content-container

Tags: layout, twitter-bootstrap

I want to do a twitter-bootstrap layout that have one sidebar on the left and the rest of the screen should be a dynamic.

Something like this:

http://wbpreview.com/previews/WB042R743/

or this:

http://wbpreview.com/previews/WB001365H/main.html

(if it asks for login: enter demo:demo)

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you take a look into the dom of the second link you'll see:

```html
<section class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2"></div>
        <div class="span10"></div>
```

the fluid classes set the width at 100% of viewport.

look into the [docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem) of twitter bootstrap

**edit**

in html:

```html
<div class="span10 content">
```

in css:

```html
.container-fluid span10.content { margin-left: 0; }
```

but remember with fluid grids twitter bootstrap defines all margins with percentage values for all spans

```html
.row-fluid [class*="span"]
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes i've had such code already, but the problem is, that there are gaps between my span-elements. How to remove them?

Comment: there are different ways to do it :) first of all, margins are a "pattern" of grids, the most grid system working with margins. if you want to remove only the margin of span10, the easiest way is to define an extra class like "content". look at my post.